# What is this external hard drive enclosure cable?

Tags: external-hard-drive, cable, enclosures

I recently found an old external hard drive enclosure that has no branding or serial numbers to look up. The only cable aside from the power cable attached to it is this. Does anyone know what type of cable this is so I can get a card reader for my computer to connect it?

http://postimage.org/image/gnq9lh3yh/

http://postimage.org/image/krzexfyrv/

http://postimage.org/image/8q0wgxwzt/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like an [external SAS cable](https://www.google.com/search?q=external%20sas%20cable&aq=f&oq=external%20sas%20cable&aqs=chrome.0.59j60l2j0l3.2258&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) to me.

Comment: This is inside the enclosure, i want to get a new card for it, one side of this cable is 4 sata connections, do you know what this side is? http://postimage.org/image/51fxtrvvj/  http://postimage.org/image/jkmurcngr/ http://postimage.org/image/ieiumon1b/